# How to stop perl message "XXX is deprecated use YYY instead" from going to stderr?

Tags: bash, perl, cron

System:

- Ubuntu 18.04 with Perl 5.26.
- I use alpine for email to get emails from cron, which are mainly messages that go to stderr.
- Searching web pages yielded no answers. So here I am.

Situation:

- I have a main Perl program, which is like a listserv program, which logs into an email account and processes email commands in each email, and determines which program to run based on commands in an email. Both the listserv like program and the called program use a list of my library routines called util2.pl. `util2.pl` has to use Mail::Sender as I could not get a newer email sending program to work in our Perl, even after searching for pages, etc. So for now, we have to use Mail::Sender.
- `util2.pl` is included in every program in the chain via `require /path/to/util2.pl`.
- I run the listserv-like program, which checks email, via a bash file and cron. So every time the bash file runs the listserv-like program, I get this error message going to stderr "Mail::Sender is deprecated...".
- In my bash file run by cron I've tried `perl /path/to/program.pl bunch of arguments 2>/tmp/stderr.txt` but I still get an email from cron with this error messages. That is, I get an email with this error message every 10 minutes of every day of the week. I end up with thousands of emails with this message.

Questions:

1. How do I get this message to stop being output? Is there a perl setting to prevent this one message? I'd like other messages to pop up like if I have an undefined variable, something is doing a numeric comparison on a non-numeric variable, etc. I would just like to disable this one "blah is deprecated" message going to stderr.
2. Or, can I set up some kind of filter to delete any messages with the error message in it? I don't know anything about filters in alpine.

Thank you so much, this has been quite a headache for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The warning comes from [this](https://metacpan.org/source/CAPOEIRAB/Mail-Sender-0.903/lib/Mail/Sender.pm#L23) line:

```
warnings::warnif('deprecated', 'Mail::Sender is deprecated and you should look to Email::Sender instead');
```

If you look into [warnings](http://p3rl.org/warnings), you'll see that a category can be turned off by

```
no warnings 'deprecated';
```

So, wrap the `use Mail::Sender` into

```
{   no warnings 'deprecated';
    use Mail::Sender;
}
```

Or directly comment out the line.

The correct solution would be to switch to Email::Sender, though. Whatever hack you implement, consider and plan a real fix, which is to stop using the deprecated library.

Comment: Thank you. Does wrapping the `no warmings 'deprecated'` wrapped in a block with the `use Mail::Sender` turn off deprecated warnings only for that block/use statement?

Comment: @Bulrush: yes, the `warnings` effect is lexically scoped to either the block or the file. However, by also loading the `Mail::Sender` module in the block, you squash the warning and the module is available to you. Anywhere else that tries to load it will see it is already loaded and not give you the warning.

Comment: @brian d foy: Very interesting! Since `util2.pl` is the first thing that loads (before any other `use` statements) in a program, just putting your code in util2.pl should fix stderr errors in all 30+ programs I have! And prevent 24*6 unneeded emails per day.